# Java code to generate comma separated values and sum

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

While running this code I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public class Evensum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int even[] = new int[num];
        int sum = 0,j = 0;
        String evennums = "";
        //Insert your code here
         for(j=0; j<=num; j++) {
            if(num%2==0) {
                even[j]=num;
                sum=sum+num;
                args[j]= Integer.toString(num);
            }
            evennums=String.join(",", args);
        }    
        System.out.println(evennums);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `j<num` in for loop.  Can't say about accessing `args` with `j` though.  Probably need to include how you would invoke this program i.e. parameters.

Comment: hi did you get this code working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j=0; j<=num; j++)
```

This is wrong. It should be:

```
for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
```

Why? Assume `num` is 5. Before this line you initialized `even` to 5. The indices of `even` would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Now, with `j<=num`, you are trying to access the index 5, which does not exist and hence the exception.

---

```
args[j]= Integer.toString(num);
```

This line will raise another exception. I am assuming you're only passing one parameter from the command line which is `args[0]`. This means the `args` array is of size 1 and you cannot add more elements to it.

Also, it is not a good practice to add/modify elements to the `args` array. You should create a new array for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the much simpler version of the Code by avoiding the `Integer.toString` and `String.join` to pass on the Arguments. Simple Integer `Arraylist` and adding the elements to will do the Trick.

```
package com.umapathy.java.learning.programs;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class EvenSum 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    int num = 20; //Initialize the user-defined value for the loop execution
    int sum = 0 ; //Initialize the Sum Value as 0
    List<Integer> evenlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Define an integer 
    Array list
    for (int i=2; i<=num; i++) //Begin the loop from the value of 2 
    {
      if(i%2==0) //Logic to find whether a given number is Even Number or not
      {
      sum = sum + i;  // If the logic returns true, Calculate the Sum Value 
      evenlist.add(i); // Add the Integer to the previous defined Integer 
                       // Arraylist by calling add method
       }        
    }
    System.out.println(evenlist); // Print the Output outside the loops
    System.out.println(sum);
     }
  }
```

Output Generated as follows:--

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20] 110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package javaApp;

public class EvenSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 20;
        int even[] = new int[num];
        int sum = 0,j = 0;
        String evennums = "";
        for(j=1; j<=num; j++) {
            if(j%2==0) {
                sum=sum+j;
                evennums=evennums+","+j;
            }
        }
        evennums=evennums.replaceFirst(",","");
        System.out.println(evennums);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation of your code sample might assist the person asking the question to better understand how this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why initialized the even array size if its actual length is unknown in initially. It's better to go with ArrayList in this case which have characteristic to grow dynamically.

**Try in this way**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int num =  Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int sum = 0;                
            for (int j = 0; j <= num; j++) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    sum += j;
                    evens.add(j);
                }
            }       
            System.out.println("Even Numbers List : "+evens);
            System.out.println("Total Sum : "+sum);
      

     // If you want an array of int instead of ArrayList you can convert ArrayList into int[] with following two lines

           int evenArray[] = even.stream().mapToInt(x->x).toArray();                
           System.out.println("Even Numbers Array : "+evenArray);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Args: "+args[0]);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int even[] = new int[num];
        int sum = 0,j = 0;
        String evennums = "";
        //Insert your code here
        for(j=0; j<=num; j++) {
            if(j%2==0) {
                //even[j]=num;
                sum=sum+j;
                if(j!=0) evennums=evennums+","+j;

            }

        }    
        evennums=evennums.substring(1);
        System.out.println(evennums);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

At time of running in eclipse follow below steps:

Right click on class--> Run AS --> Run Configuration
Go to Arguments tab and pass value as 10
Click Run
Output:
2,4,6,8,10
30